# Process hangs when running multi threading code using Java NetBeans Compiler

Tags: java, multithreading, freeze

When I run the below code which is an example of multithreading using java netbeans compiler my pc hangs.
Why does this happen?

```
class clicker implements Runnable
{
  int click=0;
  Thread t;
  private volatile boolean runn=true;
  public clicker(int p)
  {
    t=new Thread(this);
    t.setPriority(p);
  }
  public void run()
  {
    while(runn)
      click++;
  }
  public void stop()
  {
    runn=false;
  }
  public void start()
  {
    t.start();
  }
}
public class Hilopri
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    clicker hi=new clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+2);
    clicker low=new clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-2);
    low.start();
    hi.start();
    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      low.stop();
      hi.stop();
    }
    try
    {
      hi.t.join();
      low.t.join();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Low"+low.click);
    System.out.println("High"+hi.click);
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1560596 Please don't rollback to your initial post which was unreadable.

Comment: @user1560596 a lot of people with the best of intentions have tried to help you get an answer to your question. Rather than reverting the question to its original state (which many will ignore or even downvote due to poor formatting), please take it as an example of how to ask a question effectively :)

Comment: Yep Grundlefleck I will keep that in mind

Comment: Stop rolling back the changes.  Or rather, stop rolling them back after the lock is up on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call `low.stop()` and `hi.stop()` in the catch block which is only executed if `Thread.sleep(500)` throws an exception <=> is interrupted. And nothing in your code interrupts it.

You probably meant to put the stop calls in a finally block:

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        low.stop();
        hi.stop();
    }
```

Comment: also the tight loop might easily result in 100%CPU usage for one core, thus basically stopping a machine with up to 2 cores.

Comment: @JensSchauder There are other problems in the code to be honest ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens for the explanation.